# How can I add elevation/drop shadow to my drawable vector asset?

Tags: android, vector, imageview, icons, elevation

I have an image view that uses an android material icon as it's background. 
I have tried adding elevation in order to create a drop shadow effect but only the icon is displayed.
Is it possible to add elevation to a vector asset drawable?

```
   <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            />
```

Vector code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M6,18c0,0.55 0.45,1 1,1h1v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L11,19h2v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L16,19h1c0.55,0 1,-0.45 1,-1L18,8L6,8v10zM3.5,8C2.67,8 2,8.67 2,9.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5S5,17.33 5,16.5v-7C5,8.67 4.33,8 3.5,8zM20.5,8c-0.83,0 -1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5v-7c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5zM15.53,2.16l1.3,-1.3c0.2,-0.2 0.2,-0.51 0,-0.71 -0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0l-1.48,1.48C13.85,1.23 12.95,1 12,1c-0.96,0 -1.86,0.23 -2.66,0.63L7.85,0.15c-0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0 -0.2,0.2 -0.2,0.51 0,0.71l1.31,1.31C6.97,3.26 6,5.01 6,7h12c0,-1.99 -0.97,-3.75 -2.47,-4.84zM10,5L9,5L9,4h1v1zM15,5h-1L14,4h1v1z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Can you please share the vector code?

Comment: @NIKHILNEDIYODATH just updated question with vector code.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add shadow to vector drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002508/how-to-add-shadow-to-vector-drawable)

Answer (score 15):

The way I've managed to mimic a shadow effect was by drawing another vector drawable below the first one. I then shifted it down (android: translateY), so that it gives the impression that it is behind the main drawable thus sort of replicating a shadow effect. You then have to adjust the fill colour of the vector below to suit your needs.
You can then use this as a template for whatever icon you want to create a shadow effect for. All you need is to replace the path (android:pathData) with the path of the icon you want and you're good to go.

Note: for api 21 and lower you will need to place the two vectors in separate drawable files as api 21 and below doesn't allow referencing vectors inside item tags.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <vector
            android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24"
            android:viewportHeight="24">
            <group android:translateY="1">
                <path
                    android:fillColor="#73000000"
                    android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z" />
            </group>
        </vector>
    </item>

    <item>
        <vector
            android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24"
            android:viewportHeight="24">
            <path
                android:fillColor="#FFF"
                android:pathData="M19,6.41l-1.41,-1.41l-5.59,5.59l-5.59,-5.59l-1.41,1.41l5.59,5.59l-5.59,5.59l1.41,1.41l5.59,-5.59l5.59,5.59l1.41,-1.41l-5.59,-5.59z" />
        </vector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[This is the end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muIGo.png)